# Neural networks for transliteration

Tags: neural-network, transliteration

I am investigating the possibility of using neural networks for the task of transliteration (transcription from one script to another).

An example of an input = "BRAIN" and the output = "برين".

What would be the best neural network to perform this task? and how the data should be represented?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might look at this paper as a starting point. "A Deep Learning Approach to Machine Transliteration" by Thomas Deselaers

Answer (score 0):

Google has open sourced some of their transliteration models with a link to the scientific paper describing the models:

https://github.com/googlei18n/transliteration

The repository includes trained models for:

- Arabic-English
- English-Japanese
- English-IPA

They also include instructions on how to train new models (but it requires that you provide training data).